Flutter can not run in virtual device
I have trouble with running a Flutter app in a virtual device, I can run the virtual device normally but can not run it with a Flutter app.
My local.properties:
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\dat nguyen\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
flutter.sdk=C:\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=0.1.0

My gradle.properties:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

Flutter Doctor output:
C:\Users\dat nguyen>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4529], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[X] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at .\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2024.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.

When I run Flutter this error is always thrown:
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
'D:\flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

When I run the Flutter app in a virtual device, I want to run this but it always throws an error.

you have to accept the Android Licesses as showing at  flutter doctor output

Open the terminal
run flutter doctor --android-licenses
try to run the app again using flutter run command


I rann that command but it still doesn't work

You didn't add flutter to your path environment variables. This is usually done automatically but sometimes you need to do this manually

Locate Flutter Bin Directory and copy the full path
Open "Advanced system settings"
Click "Environment Variables"
Find the variable named "Path" and click Edit
Paste the full path of your Flutter bin (ex. "C:\flutter\bin")

Always make sure that the the flutter & dart bin are added to your path variables.

I have added it to patch variable, but it dosen't work

By looking at this line i can see that your flutter sdk is installed in the C drive...

flutter.sdk=C:\flutter
But this line tells me that your system is trying to run flutter from the D drive...
'D:\flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Make sure that you have configured your path correctly and used the correct path to your flutter SDK containing the flutter bin. the correct one should be the one from your C drive -> C:\flutter
